# Compressing and streaming files from a linux server

Tags: linux, scp, gzip

I have a linux server with a lot of unused files, but it is low on disk space. I'd like to take a copy of the files before deleting them. There is not enough disk space to store the compressed version before downloading.

I've tried `scp -C hostname:/path .` which is streaming down the files with compression but there are lots of tiny files which is taking a long time to copy down.

Another thread suggested a command like `ssh 10.0.0.4 "cat /tmp/backup.sql | gzip -c1" | gunzip -c > backup.sql` but that only works for one file.

Are there other methods to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
tar cf - /source | ssh 10.0.0.4 "gzip > /destination/foo.tgz"
```

but anything involving many small files will take a fair bit of time, moreso if they're in a shallow directory structure; it's just the nature of the beast.